# MySql multiple columns subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below.

```
Gowden | Year   Month   Stock Item  Plan_Stock(In Tons) Avail_Stock(In Tons)
GD1    | 2015 | Jun   | White Rice |    20             |    15
GD1    | 2015 | Jun   | Wheat      |    20             |    20
GD1    | 2015 | Jun   | Brown Rice |    10             |    10
GD2    | 2015 | Jun   | White Rice |    20             |    20
GD2    | 2015 | Jun   | Wheat      |    20             |    10
GD1    | 2015 | Jan   | White Rice |    20             |    10
GD1    | 2015 | Jan   | Wheat      |    20             |    10
GD1    | 2015 | Jan   | Brown Rice |    10             |    5
GD2    | 2015 | Jan   | White Rice |    20             |    20
GD2    | 2015 | Jan   | Wheat      |    20             |    20
GD2    | 2015 | Jan   | Brown Rice |    10             |    10
GD3    | 2015 | Jan   | White Rice |    20             |    5
GD3    | 2015 | Jan   | Wheat      |    20             |    5
GD3    | 2015 | Jan   | Brown Rice |    10             |    5
GD1    | 2014 | Jun   | White Rice |    15             |    10
GD2    | 2014 | Jun   | White Rice |    15             |    10
GD3    | 2014 | Jun   | White Rice |    15             |    10
```

I want to make a view where, it will calculate the recent available, percentage of Planned Vs Available stock item. Irrespective of items in the list. Example is GD1 recent update is on 2015 Jun. 20+20+10 = 50 tons planned. 15+20+10 =45 tons available. So % available Vs planned is 90%. as like below view.

```
Gowden | Year   Month   Stock % Precent
GD1    | 2015 | Jun   |        90%      |
GD2    | 2015 | Jun   |        75%      |
GD3    | 2015 | Jan   |        30%      |
```

Is there any way to make this in one view or i need to write script to calculate?? thanks and appreciation in advance for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried two queries.
1) SELECT gowden, year, month, 100*sum(avail_stock)/sum(plan_stock)
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY gowden 
    HAVING year=max(year) and str_to_date(month,'%b')=max(str_to_date(month,'%b'))

!Worked, but the problem i have seen is some gowdens are missing. I dont know why.

2) select gowden, year, month, 100*sum(avail_stock)/sum(plan_stock)
  from your_table
 group by gowden, year, month HAVING year=max(year) and str_to_date(month,'%b')=max(str_to_date(month,'%b')) ORDER BY gowden ASC, year, month DESC.

Worked but not only recent month, all months data will come, but sorted descending from recent year and month. 
From the view i get i can query it to get one, recent data for each gowden.

Thanks for Pablo Santa and Hitesh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select gowden, year, month, 100*sum(avail_stock)/sum(plan_stock)
  from your_table
 group by gowden, year, month
```

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot. It works but i needed only recent row for each gowden. In a year two or three updates will be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to set the approch. I haven't your schema so i can't test. It may be need to convert `month` or `year` to `date type` then apply `max` function.

```
SELECT gowden, year, month, 100*sum(avail_stock)/sum(plan_stock)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY gowden 
HAVING year=max(year) and month=max(month)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As month is not numeric one, max(month) not giving exact recent month. Tried using month=max(STR_TO_DATE(`month`,'%M')), and month=date_format(max(STR_TO_DATE(`month`,'%M')),'%M'). But recent month is not picking up.